# tokyo cabinet perl api libtokyocabinet.dylib, file is not of required architecture

Tags: macos, tokyo-cabinet

Helle there,

compiling the perl api for tokyo cabinet is diving me crazy ! i've always this error message :

> ld: warning: in
>   /usr/local/lib/libtokyocabinet.dylib,
>   file is not of required architecture

i've tried de rebuild tokyop cabinet en 64bit with

> -arch x86_64

but nothing changes ..

i'm using mac os x 10.6 (snow leopard) i'll be gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 0):

try configuring Tokyo Cabinet using

./configure --enable-off64

Comment: thank you for the response but i'm still getting the same error .. :s

i think the problem is on the file libtokyocabinet.dylib which is not compiled but only copied from installation directory to lib directory.